# Putting $n$ Things in $m$ Boxes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A bicycle collector has $100$ bikes. How many ways can the bikes be stored in four warehouses if the bikes and the warehouses are considered distinct? What if the bikes are indistinguishable and the warehouses distinct?

Comment: Highly recommended that you try to compute the number explicitly for small examples in both cases (What 3 bikes and 2 warehouses, for instance? Can you find a pattern?).

Comment: The second problem is one of finding the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 100$. A simple google search will yield plentiful resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line up the bikes in order of age, or beauty, or serial number. The first bike can go into any of the $4$ warehouses, so we have $4$ choices. For every decision about the first bike, there are $4$ decisions we can make about the second bike. So the fates of the first two bikes can be decided in $4^2$ ways.

Continue. For every decision about the fate of the first two bikes, there are $4$ choices for where the third bike goes, and so on. So there are $4^{100}$ ways to do the whole job.

You can think of an assignment of bikes to warehouses as a **function** from the set of bikes to the set of warehouses. There are $4^{100}$ such functions.

For indistinguishable bikes, we have a classical Stars and Bars problem. Perhaps you could look at the [Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) It is pretty good. This sort of question has also been answered many times on MSE.

Comment: I will look yes.

Comment: Very briefly, imagine you have $104$ bikes (yes!). Line them up in a row, with space between them. **Choose** $3$ of these spaces to put a chalk mark in. The bikes up to the first mark go into warehouse $1$, the bikes from the first mark to the second go into warehouse $2$, and so on. Now we have $104$ bikes in the warehouses, at least one in each. Remove a bike from each warehouse, and give it to me. Now you have $100$ bikes in the warehouses, with some warehouse(s) maybe empty, which is allowed. There are $\binom{103}{3}$ ways to decide where to draw the chalkmarks.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas:  Is this the same as arranging the 100 indistinguishable bikes and three indistinguishable dividers in $\binom{103}{3}$ ways?

Comment: @User58220: I find it easier to visualize the process as I briefly described it.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, we count arrangements like:

A: 1,2,...,99  B: none C: 100 D: none

Each of the bikes has four places it can go, and these choices are all independent.  By the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_principle) we count as $$4\times 4\times\cdots\times 4=4^{100}$$

For the second problem, we count arrangements like:

A: 99 bikes  B: none C: one bike D: none

You are looking for a [weak composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) of $100$ into 4 parts.  The formula for this is $${n+k-1\choose k-1}={103\choose 3}$$